Scrapy CrawlSpider Issue
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule    
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class ProductspiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "productspider"
    allowed_domains = ["oreillyauto.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.oreillyauto.com/"]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='detail'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        if response.status == 404:
            self.logger.warning(f'Page not found: {response.url}')
            return
    
        name = response.css('div.pdp-header.product-name-wrap h1::text').get()
        if name:
            yield {'name': name.strip()}
        else:
            self.logger.warning(f'No product name found at: {response.url}')

... here is my code - currently only returning 4 items out of thousands, any ideas on why it's getting stuck at just 4 items output to JSON? any help would be really appreciated. Thanks
Trying to get a list of all the products on the website, only getting 4 items from the scraper at Scrapy CrawlSpider at the moment though.

you need to add /shop/ to the LinkExtractor to crawl the list page of those details, or you will only find the detail pages on the top page https://www.oreillyauto.com/.
Here is the code:
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class ProductspiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "productspider"
    allowed_domains = ["oreillyauto.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.oreillyauto.com/"]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/detail/', '/shop/']), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        if response.status == 404:
            self.logger.warning(f'Page not found: {response.url}')
            return
        if '/detail/' in response.url:
            name = response.css('div.pdp-header.product-name-wrap h1::text').get()
            if name:
                yield {'name': name.strip()}
            else:
                self.logger.warning(f'No product name found at: {response.url}')

